# Calling virtual function in derived class

Tags: c++, object

I have 2 classes. The base class has a virtual display function and member variable shipname and date. The display() function in the base class prints the ship name. The derived class has an override of display() which also prints the ship name and a member variable y.

```
void Ship::display(){
    cout << shipName << endl << manufactureDate < <endl;
}

void CruiseShip::display(){
    cout << shipName << maxNoOfPassengers << endl;
}
```

I have a loop that calls an object from base class and object from derived class but it outputs only one ship name instead of two

When I call display from derived class I the ship name is empty, but when I call it from base object it returns its value.

```
void main(){
    Ship       sh;
    CruiseShip cruShip;
    CargoShip  cargShip;

    sh.setName("Monster");
    sh.setDate("11/11/2011");
    cruShip.setNoOfPassengers(10);
    cargShip.setCapacity(1000);
    /*Ship *x[3] = {&sh, &cruShip, &cargShip};
    for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
        x[i]->display();
    }*/
    cout<<sh.getName()<<endl;
     cout<<cruShip.getName()<<endl;
     cout<<cargShip.getName();

    system("pause");
}
```

Monster shows only from object sh

Comment: Um. Perhaps you need to call setName() on cruShip and cargShip?

Comment: You've only set the name on `sh`. What names do you expect the others to have, and why?

Comment: when i inherit from a class i get its variable which is shipName then i set shipName in sh object did it lose it value when i call it from another class??

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the attributes of your cargShip object. You set the name and date of the sh **object**, but the cargShip **object** is a whole separate object, with its own name and date that you have not set yet. Try:

```
cargShip.setName("Cargo Ship")
cargShip.setCapacity(1000);
```

Comment: when i inherit from a class i get its variable which is shipName then i set shipName in sh object did it lose it value when i call it from another class

Comment: You are confused about the difference between a class and an object. You can have multiple Ship objects. What if you had `Ship sh; Ship sh2;`

Then you can call `sh.setName("Ship1"); sh2.setName("Ship2");` Now you have 2 different ship objects with 2 different names, even if they have the same class. Similarly, sh and cargShip are completely different objects, and do not share anything with one another.

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ for more information. Make sure you understand this article and see if it helps clear this up.

Comment: okay but i have an object x which inherit from class y when a variable  in class y is set by a function i can call that variable from different derived class and it can have it value

Comment: As I said, you are very confused on the difference between an object and a class. You set the variable of an object, not the class. Setting the name of sh sets the name of the sh object of type Ship, it does **not** set the name of the Ship class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not clear how the classes are defined, whether you initialize data members of the base class in the constructor of the derived class or not.
Also I do not see that function display declared as virtual.